# Spring Property Placeholders with String Concatenation

Tags: java, spring, properties

My problem looks simple but I'm not able to resolve it. I have a properties file which contains configuration details of all environments (dev, qa, prod).

Example `config.properties`:

```
dev.maxLength=2000  
qa.maxLength=4000
```

We have a parent Properties file which holds the host name, environment mappings.

Example `hosts.properties`:

```
host1=dev
host2=qa
```

The property name `host1` is stored in a bean `hostname`.

```xml
<bean id="hostname"
  factory-bean="localhostInetAddress"
  factory-method="getHostName"/>
```

To resolve the config properties name I have to join the strings as follows,
`${${**hostname**}.maxLength}` which should be resolved as `${dev.maxLength}`

I tried using SpEL with no success. I am getting `Could not resolve placeholder` Exception. How can I concatenate a bean value in property place holder? How are dynamic property names constructed?

**Spring version 3.2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` beans to `Properties`.
`<util:properties/>` are accessible in SpEL.

Example:
`"#{prop[host+'.'+'maxLength']}"`

where `host` is a string bean.

Comment: Mind to share your XML? I' want to do the same thing but wasn't sure of what you mentioned by changing it to Properties...

Answer (score 21):

To concatenate the values parsed from Spring property placeholders, you need to escape their values using single quoutes (`''`) and wrap the placeholder expressions by a SpEL expression using `#{}`.

```
<bean id="myService" class=""com.services.MyService">
  ...
  <property name="endpointAddress" value="#{'${server}' + ':' + '${port}' + '${endpoint}'}" />
</bean>
```

where:

> server = http://domain.host.com
>
> port = 7777
>
> endpoint = /services/myservice

The result would be:

> http://domain.host.com:7777/services/myservice

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to have environment specific properties in a file of its own and use Spring Profiles.
For example, I have four xml files just for db configuration, local.db.xml, dev.db.xml, qa.db.xml and prod.db.xml.
Inside each db.xml, I set the profile to the appropriate value.

My local.db.xml has

```
<beans profile="db.local" .. >
```

For starting Tomcat, I specify the VM options as follows

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=db.local
```

Comment: I cannot use Environment variables/JVM properties, it is a policy constraint.